# Email id and name field verification use js

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have an doubt in my Register form incase i enterthis is correct format but fake id it is Acceptable my form .Any idea to Avoid to this problem....And Also I use the following code for name field text box it Allow many space i Want Only One Space in that text-box ... Any Idea?

```html
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name"   placeholder="Name" onkeyup="this.value=this.value.replace(/[^a-zA-Z ]/g,'');"required>
```

Comment: i have an doubt in case i enter<fgnj@njnn.dfm>this is correct format but fake id it is Acceptable my form .Any idea to Avoid to this problem....

Comment: No unless some one check it manually or we can just give lot of formats like that to compare during the data entry which will be very hard to do.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name"   placeholder="Name" onkeyup="this.value=this.value.replace(/[^a-zA-Z ]/g,'').replace(/\s\s+/g, ' ');"required>
```